# Show passed parameter values when walking the stack

Tags: java, reflection, stack-trace

I am attempting to write Java code that will walk the stack and print not only the method names/line numbers, but also the values that were passed in as parameters to those methods. I was able to get at StackTraceElement objects (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) for each frame as returned by Thread.getStackTrace() (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29), but this class doesn't expose the detail that I need.

Is there another approach to getting access to the stack frames / activation records that would give me the details on what was passed to each method?

Comment: Using AspectJ and intercepting on all methods.

Comment: I don't currently use AspectJ. If I include its JAR into my project what classes/methods should I look at for this?

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than that. [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) is an extension of the Java language that implements Aspect Oriented Programming. This cannot be covered here. My comment was just a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't have the luxury of moving the project to AOP.

Comment: Try using this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ThreadReference.html#frames() and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html

Comment: Using AspectJ:
before(): execution(* *(..)
thisJoinPoint.getArgs();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *may* be able to do this if you implement the [JPDA (debugger API)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/) but I doubt that you want to do that. (The performance implications could be significant, apart from anything else.)

As far as I'm aware, without that level of invasiveness, you won't be able to get at parameter values (or any other local variable values within a particular stack frame) via reflection.

Sorry for the answer to be negative, but without either that or something like AOP which you've already said you can't use, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the short answer is that what I want is just not exposed through any of the core Java components (reflection, StackElement, etc)? I will take a closer look at JPDA now, but if you are right it sounds like I am out of luck.

Comment: @tuckermi: Indeed. It's not even clear whether it would always be *feasible* to do so given JIT optimizations. Using a debugging agent *just* for this purpose would almost certainly be overkill though - but then I don't know what your context is...

Comment: Understood - yes, likely it's overkill. I have an existing large-scale system (thus the inability to change paradigms) where we took advantage of the Thread.getStackTrace() to allow us to profile/gather statistics at runtime when requested (i.e. don't pay the overhead all the time). In some cases I am interested in attributing stats at a slightly finer grain (e.g. separate foo(a) from foo(b)).

Comment: @tuckermi: Right - using the JPDA is likely to have a significant overhead, I suspect (but test, of course). I think you may need to just be explicit at the places where it's interesting, and add appropriate logging